# Ajax POST calling did not work

Tags: c#, ajax, mongodb

I am trying to create a web api with mongoDB.

This is my `model`

```
public class Entity
    {
        [BsonId]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

This `Post` method

```
public void Post(Entity entity)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var db = server.GetDatabase("Test");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<Entity>("Entities");
            collection.Save(entity);
        }
```

When I tried this with a single data it works.

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:10746/api/values",
            data: { "ID": 1, "Gender": "Male", "Name": "John" },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

But when I tried this it didn't work.

```
var entities = [
                    { "ID": 1, "Gender": "Male", "Name": "John" },
                    { "ID": 2, "Gender": "Male", "Name": "Mark" },
                    { "ID": 3, "Gender": "Male", "Name": "Tim" },
                    { "ID": 4, "Gender": "Male", "Name": "Tom" },
                    { "ID": 5, "Gender": "Female", "Name": "Julia" },
                    { "ID": 6, "Gender": "Female", "Name": "Joss" }
                ]


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:10746/api/values",
            data: entities,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

I just want to know that how can I pass an array when I call Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Posting Javascript code.

That is because your Post method accepts a single Entity object and not a list or array of Entity instances. You can change the method as follows.

```
public void Post(List<Entity> entities)
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var server = client.GetServer();
    var db = server.GetDatabase("Test");
    foreach(var entity in entities)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Entity>("Entities");
        collection.Save(entity);
    }
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
var entities = [
                    { "ID": 1, "Gender": "Male", "Name": "John" },
                    { "ID": 2, "Gender": "Male", "Name": "Mark" },
                    { "ID": 3, "Gender": "Male", "Name": "Tim" },
                    { "ID": 4, "Gender": "Male", "Name": "Tom" },
                    { "ID": 5, "Gender": "Female", "Name": "Julia" },
                    { "ID": 6, "Gender": "Female", "Name": "Joss" }
                ];

var postString = JSON.stringify(entities);


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "http://localhost:10746/api/values",
            data: postString,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried your example in fiddler with a sample service. It works for me. Can you try setting the content-type explicitly like contentType: "application/json" in your jQuery.ajax call?

Comment: I added this but it changes nothing. I just want to know that how can I pass an array when I call Ajax. @Sarathy

Comment: Your code for posting the array is correct. var postData = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; You can try adding this line to your API action for debugging and see what data is getting posted from jQuery.

Comment: the value of postData is an empty string

Comment: I have updated the code. You need to convert the object to string in jQuery. Then the Post data should work fine. For a cross browser Json.Stringify, use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js